# How can I obtain the Teams Context in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a WebPart that will be used with Sharepoint and Teams.

My question is easy, I need to retrieve the the microsoftTeams context to get the username.

How can I do it?. So far, I have something like this, but the method is deprecated.

```
import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';

export default class MyWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart <IProps> {

   private teamsContext: microsoftTeams.Context;

   protected onInit(): Promise<any> {
    let retVal: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();
    if (this.context.microsoftTeams) {
      retVal = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.context.microsoftTeams.getContext(context => {
         this._teamsContext = context;
         resolve();
      });
   });
   }
    return retVal;
   }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Try using `if (this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams)` instead of `if (this.context.microsoftTeams)`.

Comment: Error:(47, 50) TS2339: Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'IMicrosoftTeams'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `if (this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams)` instead of `if (this.context.microsoftTeams)`.

> Property `this.context.microsoftTeams` has been deprecated starting from the v1.10 release and you should be using `this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams`.

**Source**: [Detecting if web part is in Teams context](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/integrate-with-teams-introduction#detecting-if-web-part-is-in-teams-context).

**Additional Reference**: [Get context for your Microsoft Teams tab](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context).

**Update from Comments**:

You can get the teams context details using code like:

```
let siteTabTitle: string = '';
let userPrincipalName = '';
let userObjectId = '';

if (this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams) {
  siteTabTitle = "We are in the context of following Team: " + this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.teamName;

  userPrincipalName = this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.userPrincipalName;
  userObjectId = this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.userObjectId;
}
```

Where,

> - `{userPrincipalName}`: The User Principal Name of the current user, in the current tenant.
> - `{userObjectId}`: The Azure AD object ID of the current user, in the current tenant.

Comment: Hi Ganesh!

With this change:

protected onInit(): Promise<any> {
        let retVal: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();
        if (this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams) {
            retVal = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.getContext(context => {
                    this.teamsContext = context;
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        }
        return retVal;
  }

.

Comment: I have have the problem in: this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.getContext(context => {

Error:(47, 50) TS2339: Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'IMicrosoftTeams'

Comment: See updated answer to get the current user details in teams context.